# Easier way to collect beans in Poke-Pelago?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I've fully upgraded the Isle Abeens and there are a lot of Pokemon milling around:

[image: Poke-Pelago fully upgraded]

As such, collecting Pokebeans is hard because I can accidentally click on the Pokemon, which opens a dialogue with the Pelago guy about that particular Pokemon.

Is there an easier way to collect the beans then simply clicking on them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can actually **drag** the stylus across the screen instead of clicking, which will pick up the beans **but not interact with the Pokemon.**

You don't need to start on a bean either, just start on empty-space and drag a path over the beans. You can safely drag over the top of Pokemon as well: even if the bean is fully covered by a Pokemon as it hops around it will be picked up.

This is by far a much easier way to collect the beans and speeds up the process considerably.